# Did Bruce Wayne ever fight crime as a masked vigilante, before becoming the Batman?

Tags: dc, batman, dc-animated-universe

Are there any stories covering a period of time when Bruce Wayne fought crime as a masked vigilante, before dressing as the Batman?

Looking for a comic or something in the DCAU preferably.

Comment: Havn't seen it in a while but I'm pretty sure we see Bruce fighting criminals in [Mask of the Phantasm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Mask_of_the_Phantasm), and he's just wearing a ski mask.

Comment: @MajorStackings I thought Arthur was supposed to be a moth?

Comment: Ahh. Tried to be clever too early in the day. You are correct.

Comment: There was a brief period when he had a sidekick named Arthur  who dressed like a moth and Bruce used the catchphrase *Spoon!*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Mask of the Phantasm he originally goes out just wearing a ski mask. He comes back and tells Alfred he failed because they didn't fear him. Then he starts to look for a way to inspire fear in criminals and comes up with the Batman suit.

[image]

[image]

Mask of the Phantasm is kind of like Batman Year One for the DCAU.

Answer (score 3):

In the early 50's, when Bruce was a child, he learnt detective work from Harvey Harris, in order to do so he created a costume which looked like Robin's.

If I remember correctly it is in the [Untold Legends of the Batman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Untold_Legend_of_the_Batman)